How to copy text in Visual Studio Code without any line breaks?
I would like to copy text in VS Code without the line breaks in it. For example, consider this text:
This is some text. This is some text. This is 
some text. This is some text. This is some 
text. This is some text.

I would like to copy it and the result should be:
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.

How can I do this?

I don't think you can do that directly, but just after you copy it, you can select the text and use the "Find/Replace" tool: select the use of regular expressions (the little icon with ".*") and replace the line endings "\n" with blanks " ".

Thank you for your answer. I was hoping for a faster way.

maybe with an extension that allows vscode to use macros you can code one?
